# Formulation et choix de préposition dans « [...] avec le dessein de » avec un apport de qualification de « dessein » ?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, formulation

> Dans son discours de la victoire, mardi soir, le chef du Parti
>   conservateur uni, Jason Kenney, a réitéré sa promesse de lutter contre
>   les groupes écologistes canadiens qui acceptent de l'argent de
>   fondations américaines [ **avec le secret [dessein](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dessein) de** ] saboter
>   l'économie d'ici en empêchant l'Alberta d'exporter du pétrole ailleurs
>   que vers le sud. (ds. *[Alberta: Jason Kenney promet de s'en prendre
>   aux écolos](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201904/17/01-5222611-alberta-jason-kenney-promet-de-sen-prendre-aux-ecolos.php)*, LaPresse.ca)

Évidemment il y a erreur dans l'ordre des mots (secret dessein, *secret goal, plan, design* ?) mais on se demande par ailleurs si le choix de la préposition *avec* convient ici et comment intercaler l'adjectif *secret* voire l'adverbe considérant que l'emploi de [*dessein*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=dessein&id=3719) appartient semble-t-il à des tours plus ou moins figés dans des locutions (*à dessein, dans le dessein de, avoir dessein de, avoir des desseins sur qqc./qqn., sans dessein, sans-dessein*).

Comment reformule-t-on la partie de la phrase entre crochets de manière cohérente et le tour *avec comme* constitue-il une solution valable/la meilleure solution ?

Comment: pour moi la phrase est correcte, même s'il est vrai que l'adjectif se place EN GENERAL après le nom. Le placement de "secret" devant "dessein" fait peut-être écho à "noir dessein".

Comment: Petite remarque sur la formulation de la question: il me semble que "tournure" irait mieux que "tour" dans ce contexte, mais je me trompe peut-être

Comment: Pour faire écho au *«noir dessein»* mentionné ci-dessus en commentaire, je verrais aussi mieux cet ordre adjectif-nom avec *ambition: avec la secrète ambition de*.

Comment: @radouxju Pour moi ça sonne mal mais au final l'adjectif m'importe peu. Je pense qu'avec l'article je trouve la préposition _avec_ étrange quand je compare à _dans le dessein_, plus généralement je pense que la tournure est moins figée dans la citation alors que je crois qu'elle devrait l'être davantage, en plus c'est du registre plus soutenu. N'hésite pas à répondre. Pour _tour/tournure_ le TLFi donne tournure [synonyme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2) de tour, je les utilise indistinctement, je vais peut-être poser la question...

Comment: j'ai posté un commentaire au lieu d'une réponse parce que je ne parlais que de l'adjectif. Je ne sais pas quoi dire concernant la préposition "avec", qui ne me choque pas et me semble tout à fait appropriée, mais sans savoir pourquoi, ni si j'ai raison. Par ailleurs, merci pour le lien pour "tour".